# How to create a file in all directories that contain a specific file?

Tags: bash

I would like to generate an empty file "foo" in all directories that contain a file "bar" (by using the find command to find the files and then the -exec option to create the file in these directories)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it (almost):

```
find -name "bar" -execdir touch foo \;
```

`-execdir` executes from the directory in which the file was found. `touch` creates an empty file.